# Need help in understanding the meaning of an statement

Tags: intersection-theory

I getting problem in understanding the sentence

> Alpha indicates the IoU (Intersection over Union) for neighbouring candidate boxes; step sizes of the sliding windows are determined such that one step results in an IoU of Alpha.

What I understand is: The value of Alpha (which is step size) is actually the IoU (Intersection over Union) for neighbouring candidate boxes ;(further explanation of this previous sentence.) step sizes of the sliding windows can be calculated as one step produce in an IoU of Alpha.

I couldn't understand the meaning of "in an IoU of Alpha." Anyone please help me to explain this in simple words or with example

Complete Context
[image: Need help in understanding the question]

Comment: It seems that the authors talk about a sequence $B_1,B_2, B_3,\ldots$ of boxes that they want to produce by some algorithm. They intend to adjust the details and parameters of said algorithm is such a way as to guarantee $\operatorname{IoU}(B_n,B_{n+1})=\alpha$.

Comment: let me explain in step wise, please correct me if I miss understood anything. From some algorithm we have candidate bounding boxes. Then we search the bounding boxes using sliding window search. Then the step size is determined using a single parameter α. So does it means α is a step size?